# Modular inequality of sequential terms: $|x_ny_n-xy| \le |x||y_n-y|+|y_n||x_n-x|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How can I prove that $|x_ny_n-xy| \leq |x||y_n-y|+|y_n||x_n-x| $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x_ny_n-xy=x(y_n-y)+y_n(x_n-x)$$
and then use [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) (norm properties).